# MyLocationOverlay is deprecated, any alternative?

Tags: android, osmdroid, mylocationoverlay

MyLocationOverlay is deprecated. Is there any alternative?

```
MapView mapView;
MyLocationOverlay myLocationoverlay;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    ...
```

Comment: Please consider choosing a correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new class is the **MyLocationNewOverlay**.

Comment: @LaurentMeyer open a pull request to rename it. I nearly did it myself several times, but there was some concern about backwards compatibility.